# How can I manually count the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, built-in

I'm  trying to find length of array without built-in length property. Is this a right way? It is going in infinite loop.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let i;
let count = 0;

while (array[i] != 'undefined') {
  console.log(array[i]);
  i++
  count++;
}

console.log("length of array is" + count);
```

Comment: This isn‘t the best place to ask these questions, you would be better off looking on mdn and look at the examples, and to answer your question, no, that isn‘t the right way. You can use the arrays `length` property

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will result in an infinite loop !!

Firstly, you have declared `i` but have not initialized it with a value. This means `i` will be `undefined`, and when you use it as an index to access `array[i]`, it will always be `undefined`, resulting in an infinite loop.

Secondly, in your while loop condition, you are checking `array[i] != 'undefined'`. This comparison should be `array[i] !== undefined` (without the quotes around undefined). The undefined keyword should not be treated as a string in this case.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let i = 0;
let count = 0;

while (array[i] !== undefined) {
    console.log(array[i]);
    i++;
    count++;
}

console.log("Length of array is " + count);
```

I hope I helped you learn something new today ;)

Comment: thanks a lot.I understood my mistake.But is this a correct way to find length of an array without builtin?

Comment: "Correct" is a matter of opinion. If it works, it works. If there's a simpler or more readable way to do it, that may be _more_ correct. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your way can work with the fixes proposed by zoldxk. However, a modern `forEach()` loop seems simpler here. You don't need to bother with indexes.

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let count = 0;

array.forEach(element => {
  count++;
});

console.log("length of array is " + count);
console.log('array.length is', array.length);
```